# Find index of recently used list element Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I am building a recipe app. I created a database of recipes, where the information is set using the ArrayList. My idea is to create a "Recent Recipes" section, in which the templates I created earlier were replaced with buttons on the recipe itself.
Question: how to find the index of the three previous used recipes?

My database:
`

```
public class ReceiptsBase {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> recipesAll = new ArrayList<>();

    public ReceiptsBase() {
        ArrayList<Integer> mushroom_soup = new ArrayList<>();
        mushroom_soup.add (R.drawable.mush);
        mushroom_soup.add (R.string.mush_name);
        mushroom_soup.add (R.string.mush_info);
        mushroom_soup.add (R.string.mush_prep);
        mushroom_soup.add(R.drawable.mush_blur);
        mushroom_soup.add(R.string.mush_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> tomato_soup = new ArrayList<>();
        tomato_soup.add (R.drawable.tomato);
        tomato_soup.add (R.string.tomato_name);
        tomato_soup.add (R.string.tomato_info);
        tomato_soup.add (R.string.tomato_prep);
        tomato_soup.add(R.drawable.tomato_blur);
        tomato_soup.add(R.string.tomato_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> potato_soup = new ArrayList<>();
        potato_soup.add (R.drawable.potatosoup);
        potato_soup.add (R.string.potsoup_name);
        potato_soup.add (R.string.potsoup_info);
        potato_soup.add (R.string.potsoup_prep);
        potato_soup.add(R.drawable.potatosoup_blur);
        potato_soup.add(R.string.potsoup_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> onion_meal = new ArrayList<>();
        onion_meal.add (R.drawable.onion);
        onion_meal.add (R.string.onion_name);
        onion_meal.add (R.string.onion_info);
        onion_meal.add (R.string.onion_prep);
        onion_meal.add(R.drawable.onion_blur);
        onion_meal.add(R.string.onion_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> pancakes = new ArrayList<>();
        pancakes.add (R.drawable.pancakes);
        pancakes.add (R.string.pank_name);
        pancakes.add (R.string.pank_info);
        pancakes.add (R.string.pank_prep);
        pancakes.add(R.drawable.pancakes_blur);
        pancakes.add(R.string.pank_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> dumplings = new ArrayList<>();
        dumplings.add (R.drawable.dumpl);
        dumplings.add (R.string.dumpl_name);
        dumplings.add (R.string.dumpl_info);
        dumplings.add (R.string.dumpl_prep);
        dumplings.add(R.drawable.dumpl_blur);
        dumplings.add(R.string.dumpl_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> croquettes = new ArrayList<>();
        croquettes.add (R.drawable.croquettes);
        croquettes.add (R.string.croq_name);
        croquettes.add (R.string.croq_info);
        croquettes.add (R.string.croq_prep);
        croquettes.add(R.drawable.croquettes_blur);
        croquettes.add(R.string.croq_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> katsudon = new ArrayList<>();
        katsudon.add (R.drawable.katsudon);
        katsudon.add (R.string.kats_name);
        katsudon.add (R.string.kats_info);
        katsudon.add (R.string.kats_prep);
        katsudon.add(R.drawable.katsudon_blur);
        katsudon.add(R.string.kats_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> garlic_bread = new ArrayList<>();
        garlic_bread.add (R.drawable.garlic);
        garlic_bread.add (R.string.garl_name);
        garlic_bread.add (R.string.garl_info);
        garlic_bread.add (R.string.garl_prop);
        garlic_bread.add(R.drawable.garlic_blur);
        garlic_bread.add(R.string.garlic_ingr);

        ArrayList<Integer> potato_pancakes = new ArrayList<>();
        potato_pancakes.add (R.drawable.pot_pank);
        potato_pancakes.add (R.string.potpank_name);
        potato_pancakes.add (R.string.potpank_info);
        potato_pancakes.add (R.string.potpank_prep);
        potato_pancakes.add(R.drawable.pot_pank_blur);
        potato_pancakes.add(R.string.potpank_ingr);

        recipesAll.add(mushroom_soup);
        recipesAll.add(tomato_soup);
        recipesAll.add(potato_soup);
        recipesAll.add(onion_meal);
        recipesAll.add(pancakes);
        recipesAll.add(dumplings);
        recipesAll.add(croquettes);
        recipesAll.add(katsudon);
        recipesAll.add(garlic_bread);
        recipesAll.add(potato_pancakes);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getReceipt(int receiptIndex) {
        return recipesAll.get(receiptIndex);
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getReceipts() {
        return recipesAll;
    }
```

`

[The section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHxSf.png)

My code:`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hideSystemUI();

        Button button_recipes = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button_recipes.setOnClickListener(view -> openRecipes());

        Button button_search = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button_search.setOnClickListener(view -> openSearch());

        Button button_supriseme = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button_supriseme.setOnClickListener(view -> openSupriseMe());

        ImageButton recent1 = findViewById(R.id.rec1);
        ImageButton recent2 = findViewById(R.id.rec2);
        ImageButton recent3 = findViewById(R.id.rec3);

//        recent1.setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
//        recent2.setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
//        recent3.setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
//
//        recent1.setOnClickListener(view -> openRecipe());
//        recent2.setOnClickListener(view -> openRecipe());
//        recent3.setOnClickListener(view -> openRecipe());

    }
    public void openRecipes(){
        Intent rec = new Intent(this, recipes.class);
        startActivity(rec);
        finish();
    }
    public void openSearch(){
        Intent sea = new Intent(this, search.class);
        startActivity(sea);
        finish();
    }
    public void openSupriseMe(){
        Intent sup = new Intent(this, Example.class);
        startActivity(sup);
        finish();
    }
    public void openRecipe(int recipeIndex){
        Intent sup = new Intent(this, Example.class);
        sup.putExtra("recipeIndex", recipeIndex);
        startActivity(sup);
        finish();
    }
```

`

Comment: what do you mean most recent recipes?  Are they the most recently viewed recipes?  Why not just add them to a list named recent?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with length three and add a recipe there when it is used. When the array is full and a recipe is used, set:

```
array[0] = array[1];
array[1] = array[2];
array[2] = most recently used.
```

or, of course, you could do it the other way around, where array[0] is the most recently used. That would be:

```
Recipe temp0 = array[0]
array[0] = most recently used
Recipe temp1 = array[1]
array[1] = temp0;
array[2] = temp1;
```

I don't know what type of Object your recipes are, so I just called them type Recipe.